# ICU collation rules with empty strings

Tags: unicode, icu

I'm only starting to work with ICU  collation rules and I have a question about how I can create a rule applying to empty string.
In short, if I have the following list:

```
"", "abc", "", "def"
```

I would like to create a rule so that, after sorting, the empty strings will be at the end of the list:

```
"abc", "def", "", ""
```

The character set is not restricted to only Latin, so the rule should be apply to the whole range of Unicode points. I have tried this without success:

```
"&[last regular] < \u0000"
```

I also tried looking at some options that the API offers but did not find anything of use.

My question: is it possible to create such a rule? As I said, I am not very familiar with the API and the semantics of the rules, but I suspect that it is not possible, since the empty string does not have any Unicode points to attach weights to.

Thank you!